# Directory confusion with Express JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, connection

To require our own modules, how should the directory structure look like? For example if a module in a folder called modules is requiring a module from a database folder, would it look like this?:

```
var db = require('./database/db.js')
```

The problem I am facing is that I have this code requiring one of my modules:

```
//Require mysql connector that you installed with npm
var mysql      = require('./mysql_conn');
```

and this is my directory structure:

http://prntscr.com/1yfsej

The file that is requiring the module is in the routes folder, and the file is in the db folder. I keep getting this error:

http://prntscr.com/1yfsjb

//Require mysql connector that you installed with npm
   var mysql      = require('./mysql');

var conn_conf = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : 3306,
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'nutrition_tracker'
  }

```
      var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn_conf);

  exports.connection.connect(function(err) {
   if(err) console.log("Could not connect to DB");
    else{
    console.log("Connected to "+conn_conf.database+' on '+conn_conf.host );

    return connection
    }
});
```

Comment: //Require mysql connector that you installed with npm
var mysql      = require('./mysql');

var conn_conf = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : 3306,
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'nutrition_tracker'
}

var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn_conf);

exports.connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) console.log("Could not connect to DB");
    else{
        console.log("Connected to "+conn_conf.database+' on '+conn_conf.host );
     
     return connection
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

You can 'require' user-written modules without the js extension like

```
var db = require('./database/db')
```

For the other module, you need to refer the mysql_conn wrt to the db file.

```
//Require mysql connector that you installed with npm
var mysql      = require('../mysql_conn');
```

Comment: I'm doing this: var db = require('./db/mysql_conn'), but it still gives me theerror that mysql_conn cannot be found. mysql_conn is in the folder db. If im requiring it in a .js file that is within a folder called 'routes', how do I correctly specify the path? like so?: .(root)/db(folder)/mysql_conn(file)?

Comment: Did you try ../db/mysql_conn. It is the relative path of mysql_conn with respect to the current file.